# How to filter sub JSON objects in postman API

Tags: json, api, object, filter, postman

I might not even be using the proper terminology, so I apologize in advance.

I am using Postman to run API calls to collect data for clients and my own research and I need to filter the request by a "sub object" (again not sure about the terminology)

This is the call I used to get the below response:

```
https://apicfa.convirza.com/v2/call/dni?filter=group_id=8361&limit=10


{
    "result": "success",
    "err": null,
    "data": [
        {
            "call_id": "6834916",
            "call_flow_id": 22830,
            "group_id": 8361,
            "disposition": "ANSWERED",
            "duration": 27,
            "caller_id": "5551234545",
            "tracking_number": "5551234545",
            "ring_to": "5551234545",
            "repeat_call": false,
            "call_started": "2018-05-03T21:30:35.000Z",
            "dni_data": {
                "browser": "Chrome/(Android; Android 7.1.1)",
                "created_at": "2018-05-03T21:30:10.000Z",
                "custom_params": {},
                "destination_url": "",
                "dni_vid": "",
                "first_page": "",
                "ga_cid": "",
                "ip_host": "",
                "last_page": "",
                "log_date": "2018-05-03 21:30:10 UTC",
                "location_details": {

                },
                "ref_param": {
                    "utm_medium": "cpc",
                    "utm_campaign": "GT:Tampa",
                    "utm_source": "google"
                },
                "master_node_id": 8361,
                "organizational_unit_id": 8361,
                "referring": "https://google.com",
                "referring_type": "Paid",
                "referring_url": "",
                "search_words": "Not Provided",
                "session_id": "",
                "updated_at": "",
                "gclid": "EwE",
                "gclsrc": "",
                "phone_numbers": {
                    "id": 60270626,
                    "dni_log_id": "5aeb7f628a95c63fe500055b",
                    "dni_id": "3798",
                    "phone_number": "5551234545",
                    "element": "cfa_eps",
                    "phone_number_id": "",
                    "pool_id": "6118",
                    "number_last_used": "2018-05-03 21:30:10 UTC",
                    "provisioned_route_id": "22830"
                }
            }
        },
```

What I would like to do is filter by "**custom_params**" or "**utm_medium**" but I can not fiqure out how to get to that level. Any help would be greatly appretiated.

Comment: What do you mean by filtering it? Do you want to check a specific value in a test?

Comment: Danny, I use Postman to extract data from call records and not as a developer. My goal is to get results like above, extract it, convert it to csv and then present the data to clients. So when I say filter I would like to return all call detail records that meet a specific criteria i.e calls from Google paid...

Answer (score 2):

You can try as following;

```
var responsedata = pm.response.json();

if(responsedata.length > 0) {
    responsedata.data.forEach(function(data) {
        var dniData = data.dni_data
        var customParams = dniData.custom_params
        pm.test("customParams not empty", function () {
            pm.expect(customParams).to.not.equal(null);
        });
        pm.environment.set("customParams", customParams);

        var refParams = dniData.ref_param
        pm.test("refParams not empty", function () {
            pm.expect(refParams).to.not.equal(null);
        });

        var utmMedium = refParams.utm_medium
        pm.test("utmMedium not empty", function () {
            pm.expect(utmMedium).to.not.equal("");
        });
        pm.environment.set("refParams", refParams);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is using a mixture of old and new Postman syntax, I would recommend editing this to use the newer stuff. You don’t need to JSON.parse the responseBody anymore as `pm.response.json()` does this. `tests[]` has been replaced by the `pm.test()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is a late response, but it can help other people.
Using "JsonPath" this maybe be a solution.

**For custom_params use this:**
`$.data[*].dni_data.custom_params`

**And, for utm_medium, use this:**
`$.data[*].dni_data.ref_param.utm_medium`

I hope to help the new viewers.